# I am trying to upload multiple images to SFTP server but right now I am able to upload only one at a time?

Tags: ios, objective-c, file-upload, nmssh

I am using NMSSH to connect to SFTP Server from my ios application. I am able to upload one image at a time to server. But want to upload multiple images at once. How can I achieve this. Please suggest.

```
NMSSHSession *session = [NMSSHSession connectToHost:@"host"
                                           withUsername:@"user"];
    if (session.isConnected) {
        if (!session.isAuthorized) {
            NSArray *authTypes = [session supportedAuthenticationMethods];   
        }

        NSString *privateKey = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"privatekey" ofType:nil];
        [session authenticateByPublicKey:nil
                              privateKey:privateKey
                             andPassword:nil];

        if (session.isAuthorized) {
            NSLog(@"Authentication succeeded");
        }
    }

    NMSFTP *sftp = [[NMSFTP alloc] initWithSession:session];
    [sftp connect];
```

The requirement is like user will take multiple photos using the camera or image picker and I need to save them locally and once they hit sync button I should send/upload all the images to sftp server.

Right now I am trying this functionality in a demo application so I dont have the images from camera or image picker. For testing I am just using the images in my resource.

Below is the sample:-

```
UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"flower.jpg"];
 UIImage *image2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Wall.jpg"];
 UIImage *image3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Circle.jpg"];
 NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
 NSMutableData *data2 = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
 NSMutableData *data3 = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];

[data appendData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image1)];
[data2 appendData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image2)];
[data3 appendData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image3)];

[sftp writeContents:data toFileAtPath:@"serverPath/image1.jpg"];
[sftp writeContents:data2 toFileAtPath:@"serverPath/image2.jpg"];
[sftp writeContents:data3 toFileAtPath:@"serverPath/image3.jpg"];
[session disconnect];
```

Comment: What's your code to upload an image?

Comment: @Larme I have updated my question with the code.

Comment: I don' know about NMSSH, but clearly, that seems wrong. You are appending all the images, and use the same path? That's really really weird. Do: `[sftp writeContents:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image1) toFileAtPath:@"serverPath/filename1.jpg"];[sftp writeContents:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image2) toFileAtPath:@"serverPath/filename2.jpg"];[sftp writeContents:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image3) toFileAtPath:@"serverPath/filename3.jpg"];` instead.

Comment: @Larme Actually I am doing the way you proposed. But in this way it is calling n number of times the server right? So thats what I thought is not a good way to call so many times. And asked how can I send all the images at once.